# AC3 Codec for MX Amlogic MX2 Android Media Player Box

Tags: audio, mx-player

OK, so I have just bought the MX Amlogic MX2 Android Media Player, and I see that it doesn't play the most common audio file, AC3. I know that there are some licencing issues, and I also know that there is some workaround for this, but as I am a technophobe for all things with googly amps, could anyone please provide me with a step-by-step walk-through to show me how to get AC3 Audio?

For instance, do I need to connect the box to the internet to connect to the appropriate website, or can I just download the needed codec onto a memory stick (via my PC) and upload it to my MX2 Player? Aaaaand, where can I find the codec?

Hoping someone can help me..... :-)

Answer (score 0):

AC3 is not by any means the most common file type/format for audio files.
MP3 and Apple's AAC/m4a is do l far more often used especially on mobile devices and on the internet.

Downloading codecs like on PC is not possible. Android has to ship it in it's system or your media player has to support AC3 files.
This is also not very easy because AC3 is patented and licensed so developers have to use free codecs.

Comment: The MX device I have is a media player. I use to watch films on my TV. Most of the films have AC3 audio. On another thread here (AC3 Codec for MX Player) I saw info that I believed would enable me to download an apk file onto my media player to enable AC3 audio for my films. It seems this is not the case & applies only to the MX Player program, not media players? If so, is there another option  to enable AC3 audio? FYI, I did download the 1.7.32 version of MX Player and downloaded it to my media player, but of course, it didn't change anything.... that shows you my level of technophobia! >-)

Comment: I quickly check this on my device. Also: As far as I know there is no way to *enable* AC3 for media players that are not designed for playing those files. Many utilize the Android internal `MediaPlayer` which is limited to the formats specified by the Android docs.

Comment: I haven't found a way to play those files. I think this is mainly because of the audio output stream which is limited to 2 channels (left/right) only.

Comment: Well, the media player was designed to play AC3 audio, but the player manufacturer had to remove the function due to them not paying the licence fee.

Comment: That makes sense. I remember that MX Player was advertised to play surround audio (ie. AC3). Seems that we have to convert it back to a normal format (WAV/FLAC for lossless, MP3 for lossy).